# Windows 10 missing all installed software in start menu

Tags: windows-10

Just now I ran into some troubles on Windows 10 where the start menu wouldn't open anymore. I was able to solve this by deleting \AppData\Local\TileDataLayer and running `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}` in Powershell.

This brought back my start menu but all the software I installed myself (except the apps installed through the store) are missing, only Windows components and said apps are present despite the shortcuts still being in AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs. This also caused the start menu search not to find any of the programs which is a common way for me to launch programs so quite the annoyance. A reboot didn't solve my problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All my software is back, I guess it just took some time to re index everything.